# Query time after partition in postgres

Tags: postgresql, partition

I have table `location` in postgres database with more then 50.000.000+ rows, and i decide to do partition! 
Table `parent` have columns `id,place` and i want to do partition on`place` column, with php and mysql i get all distinct places(about 300) and foreach

```
CREATE TABLE child_place_name (CHECK (place=place_name))INHERITS(location)
```

and after that in each child table

```
 INSERT INTO child_place_name SELECT * FROM location WHERE place=place_name
```

and that works perfectly!
After i delete rows from parent class with

```
DELETE FROM location WHERE tableoid=('location'::regclass)::oid;
```

i that affected all rows is table!
Then i try to do query and a get times and realize that now is time  for query 3 or more times longer then before.
I also have problem that my affect on speed: first i can't set primary key on id column in child tables, but i set index key on place(also index is set on place column in  parent table), and also i can't set unique key on id and place columns i got error multiple parameters in not allowed(or something like that)

All i want is select side of table i don't need rules or triggers to set when i insert in parent table,cause that is another problem,only i want to  know what is wrong with this approach!Maybe 300+ tables is to much?

Comment: postgres partitions work on rules - you cant avoid it. what did you want to do with `DELETE FROM location WHERE tableoid=('location'::regclass)::oid;`?.. postgres does not support global PK on partitioned tables like oracle.

Comment: Is need rule for SELECT statement? This is my first time to do partititon